# If switching img src and then back again will the image be loaded twice?

Tags: javascript, html, image, caching

If i have an image element with a default src(ex. img1.jpg) and then with javascript change to a different image(ex. img2.jpg) it will load the first image and then the second image.

But if i change back to the original image(img1.jpg), will that image be loaded again(total load times: 2)? or is it cached in any way. 
If not, is there any convenient way to cache it when doing such a thing?

Comment: Yes, but if the cache control says to cache, it loads from the cache.

Comment: @PraveenKumar so if no Cache-control meta data has been set, it will not cache?

Comment: It gets it from the server if it is not there. Yes!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image src will load the image once so if you have "img1.jpg" many times in the page will only load it once but it will render it multiple times. So to answer your question you will not have a problem loading it again and again like in your example.

Comment: this will affect when there will be a page refresh

Comment: Ok, thank you. gonna try it out and then accept if it works :)

Answer (score 0):

Modern Browsers these days create cache and maintain it till the session. In your case if img1.jpg is loaded first by the browser its cached though its being replaced by img2.jpg later. but if you go back to img1 it will load much faster as its cached already

Comment: no if you have specified no Cache-control meta then  browser will not cache it and it will definately take time to load image again and again